# What is the difference between Python's unittest and unittest2 modules?

Tags: python-3.x, compatibility, python-2.x, python-module, python-unittest

I currently work on some code that uses unittest2 module. I suspect this code was meant for the python2. Can one use python3 unittest as a drop in replacement for unittest2? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [Python 2.7 unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html):

> unittest2: A backport of new unittest features for Python 2.4-2.6 Many
>   new features were added to unittest in Python 2.7, including test
>   discovery. unittest2 allows you to use these features with earlier
>   versions of Python.

So moving from `unittest2` under Python 2 to `unittest` under Python 2.7 or Python 3 should do exactly what you want

Comment: `unittest2` seems also to support some advanced function not supported by `unittest`. For example, `subTest` which is supported from `Python3.4`.